# Avoid the exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError without growing the heap space?

Tags: scala

I met a problem with the Java heap space in which I try to group the consecutive elements of one array in order to create a matrix for computing his transposed. I have a lot of values in the array (26726400) and I try to have buckets of size 29. But when I tested the following code, I get the exception `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

```
val arr = new Array[Int](256 * 3600 * 29)
    arr: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
scala> arr.grouped(29).toArray
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

My purpose is to transpose the matrix. If I run `sbt -mem 2048`, this code works but is it an another way to do this task without growing the heap space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not save much memory, though it is surely more efficient than `grouped`, which does a couple of copies between buffers internally.

```
scala> val arr = new Array[Int](256 * 3600 * 29)
arr: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0,...

scala> Array.tabulate(256 * 3600, 29)((i,j) => arr(i * 29 + j))
res0: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 0, 0,...
```

It's noticeably faster in my scientific trial.

You could also use 1-dim tabulate, allocate `Array.ofDim(29)` and `Array.copy`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the default memory for a JVM instance on machines with >1Gb of RAM is RAM/4. So, add more memory to your computer, and you won't have to pass that parameter to sbt.

Joking aside, you have at least 3 copies of the data here. First is the original `arr` instance, then the result of `grouped` operation, then the result of `toArray` call. And it could even be more, I'm not sure about the implicit conversion to `ArrayOps`, which is required by calling the `grouped` method (it's not defined on the `Array` class, actually).

Given your data size and type, one copy takes ~101Mb of memory, excluding any overhead associated with storage. To solve the problem, reduce the amount of copies you make. For example, I don't really understand why you need the last `toArray` call.

As a side note, if it's not a homework, consider using some existing libraries for matrix operations, like jBLAS.

Comment: I call `toArray` because I need to apply the function `transpose` on the 2D array.